# PyQGIS 3 Set Svg marker symbol

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology, pyqgis-3

I would like to add my own SVG symbol instead of a dot. I tried the following.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
svgStyle = {}
svgStyle['fill'] = '#0000ff'
svgStyle['name'] = path
svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
svgStyle['outline-width'] = '6.8'
svgStyle['size'] = '6'
symbol = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer.create(svgStyle)
layer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
```

Unfortunately the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: QgsSingleSymbolRenderer.setSymbol(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer'
```

Answer (score 4):

[QgsSingleSymbolRenderer.setSymbol()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSingleSymbolRenderer.html#a3e37402a60195abd7fa5283abf50afc7) need a `QgsSymbol` object not `QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer`.

To set the symbol you can use this, where we are changing the default style (0).

```
symbol = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer(path)
symbol.setSize(6)
symbol.setFillColor(QColor('#0000ff'))
symbol.setStrokeColor(QColor('#ff0000'))
symbol.setStrokeWidth(1)
layer.renderer().symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol )
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Now there is no more error, but a question mark appears instead of my symbol. I used this path 'landmark/tourism=museum.svg' with a new temporary layer with dots.

Comment: @daniel95 I updated the answer showing how to show path and properties. Please check.